Vote or remove tag synonym suggestion [angular-module] to [angularjs-module]
In 2014, a tag synonym suggestion has been created from angular-module to angularjs-module which is stuck at 0 votes.
At the time, Angular (2+) has neither been released nor announced yet, and the suggestion was totally valid.
However in the meantime Angular has been released, and there were some meta discussions on how to handle the ambiguity between AngularJS and Angular (2+).
The result is that AngularJS-related tags are prefixed with angularjs-, and Angular-related tags are prefixed with angular-, which is common practice today.
According to this approach, the given tags are not synonyms, as they are about two different tools.
So I ask everyone with a sufficient score to vote on the tag suggestion, or the mods to handle it.
It bothers me because I am trying to create a new synonym suggestion from the ng-modules tag to the angular-module tag, but I am unable to create it due to this pending suggestion.

Interestingly, somehow I cannot locate the synonym proposal in both active and pending approval page of tag synonym

On those pages I also cannot see this suggestion, maybe only those are listed which you are eligible to vote on.
